# OpenLayers 3 restrict map to an area

Tags: openlayers

I want to restrict the OpenLayers 3 [heatmap-earthquakes examle](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/examples/heatmap-earthquakes.html) to show only Europe.

I have:

```
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.Stamen({
    layer: 'toner-background'
  })
});

var map = new ol.Map({

  layers: [raster, vectorLayer],
  target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        center: [0, 0],
        maxZoom: 9,
        minZoom: 0,
        zoom: 4
  })
});
```

Let`s say that the points:

```
var point1 = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([-20.000000, 28.000000], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
var point2 = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([50.000000, 73.000000], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

are the bounds of Europe, how can I restrict the map view only between the two point?

Comment: you can do min/max zoom based on a coordinate http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/zoom-constrained.html

Answer (score 4):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200086/restrict-pan-outside-wms-extent-in-openlayers3) was asked here on StackOverflow some time ago.

So, although a patch (and a pull request) [exists](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/2777), what you want is not yet supported by OpenLayers 3.

For now you may want to use the `extent` option of `ol.View`. As the docs [say](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.View.html?unstable=true), with this option, you can constrain the center of the view in a way that it cannot be outside of the given extent.

And you can also use the `minZoom` or `maxResolution` options (of `ol.View` again) to prevent the user from zooming out. The [zoom-constrained](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/zoom-constrained.html) example pointed to by @Mapperz in his/her comment demonstrates the use of these options.

Comment: Is this still the best solution to this problem? Because the extent option is not really solving this... I am looking forward to have something similar to this: http://www.bing.com/mapspreview/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#maxBounds+TS