# OpenLayers3 how to limits the drag range of the map

Tags: openlayers

I use OpenLayers3 to display a tile map, but there is a blank area on the top and bottom of the map, how to limit the drag range so that it does not display the blank area.[image]

Comment: You may use the ol.view extent option. [here is a similar question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127834/openlayers-3-restrict-map-to-an-area)

Comment: yes, but when you zoom in, the user still cannot drag the map

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/168388)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set extent option to ol.View. As you can see options of ol.View from [api doc](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html), it restricts the ranges that the center can be moved. 
simply set like:

```
new ol.View({
  extent: [minx, miny, maxx, maxy]
});
```

then the area that map can be moved will be set as extent option.